# How to add custom check status in PR for Gtihub actions

Tags: github-actions, github-api

I'm using GitHub super-linter and like its feature to set multiple detailed statuses that can be checked via UI (`--> Linted: ...`):

[image: Github Actions Statuses]

I'm [learning how it works](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/statuses#create-a-commit-status) and trying to implement same feature.

The successed status `triggered on multiple PR events` at the picture is simply printing out GitHub context and environment variables of this job.

So I used these ENVs and created simple script:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

CTX="test context"
GITHUB_API_URL=api.github.com
GITHUB_REPOSITORY=org-name/repository-name
GITHUB_SHA=sha_that_i_copied_from_printed_data
GITHUB_TOKEN=ghp_secretsecretsecret
GITHUB_RUN_ID=12345678_also_copied_from_job_printed_envs

curl --show-error -X POST \
  --url "https://${GITHUB_API_URL}/repos/${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}/statuses/${GITHUB_SHA}" \
  -H 'accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' \
  -H "authorization: Bearer ${GITHUB_TOKEN}" \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d "{ \"state\": \"error\",
    \"target_url\": \"https://${GITHUB_DOMAIN:-github.com}/${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}/actions/runs/${GITHUB_RUN_ID}\",
    \"description\": \"set to failed\", \"context\": \"${CTX}\"
  }"
```

When I run it I've got response like:

```json
{
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/org-name/repository-name/statuses/sha_that_i_copied_from_printed_data",
  "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/12345678?v=4",
  "id": 1234567890,
  "node_id": "SC_ABCDEF0123456-iw",
  "state": "error",
  "description": "set to failed",
  "target_url": "https://github.com/...",
  "context": "test context",
  "created_at": "2023-03-13T13:42:54Z",
  "updated_at": "2023-03-13T13:42:54Z",
  "creator": {
    "login": "user",
    "id": 123456789,
    "node_id": "ABCDEF123456",
    "avatar_url": "https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/12345678?v=4",
    "gravatar_id": "",
    "url": "https://api.github.com/users/user",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/",
    "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/user/followers",
    "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/user/following{/other_user}",
    "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/user/gists{/gist_id}",
    "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/user/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
    "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/user/subscriptions",
    "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/user/orgs",
    "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/user/repos",
    "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/user/events{/privacy}",
    "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/user/received_events",
    "type": "User",
    "site_admin": false
  }
}
```

Also when I'm trying to get statuses by using:

```bash
curl -L \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ${GITHUB_TOKEN}"\
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  "https://${GITHUB_API_URL}/repos/${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}/statuses/${GITHUB_SHA}"
```

It's working good too and I able to see all statuses that I added.

But. I can't see any changes in UI. `triggered on multiple PR events` Job is still marked as successfully completed and no new status appear in list (like `--> Linted: ...` in case of super-linter). So what I'm doing wrong and how to add statuses that can be browsed via UI?

I tried to add manually by running `curl` from my PC and by using Github Actions (and used EVNs like `GITHUB_SHA` of actual job). Result is the same - nothing happens in UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `GITHUB_SHA` wasn't correct. `head SHA` (it can be found in `github.event.after` context variable) should be used to add status.

Also `github.event.pull_request.statuses_url` context variable may be used to get `statuses` URL as is. So I used this workflow to add extra check status:

```yaml
---
name: Some Test

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - test/*
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - develop

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Run Test

    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
      statuses: write
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      STATUSES_URL: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.pull_request.statuses_url || '' }}

    steps:
      - name: Add error status
        run: |
          if [ -n "${GITHUB_TOKEN}" ] && [ -n "${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}" ] && [ -n "${STATUSES_URL}" ]; then
            curl -f -s --show-error -X POST \
              --url "${STATUSES_URL}" \
              -H 'accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json' \
              -H "authorization: Bearer ${GITHUB_TOKEN}" \
              -H 'content-type: application/json' \
              -d "{ \"state\": \"error\",
                \"target_url\": \"https://${GITHUB_DOMAIN:-github.com}/${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}/actions/runs/${GITHUB_RUN_ID}\",
                \"description\": \"following after context description\", \"context\": \"some message here\"
                 }"
          fi
```